# Trying to install plugin "Preview HTML", and failing

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, plugins

Notepad++ version 6.8.8.

Windows 7.

Notepad++ installed as administrator.

Can install some other plugins, but not "Preview HTML".

During installation, a dialog box pops up with title "Installation Error".
The dialog message says "Installation of Preview HTML failed."

This dialog box appears before the plugin has downloaded.

I get the same error also when trying to install the plugin on XP.

Comment: Duplicated here. There is an open bug [Unable to install preview html plugin](http://chiselapp.com/user/vor0nwe/repository/npp_preview/tktview?name=8a9c7bb008)

Comment: Note last update to this plugin was v1.3.1.0, 2013-07-14. I'm trying a manual install.

Comment: Manual install works and passes basic testing. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### The dialog message says "Installation of Preview HTML failed"

There is an open bug [Unable to install preview html plugin](http://chiselapp.com/user/vor0nwe/repository/npp_preview/tktview?name=8a9c7bb008):

[image]

I can reproduce this problem.

**Workaround**

A manual install was successful and the plugin appears to work (I haven't tested it thoroughly).

---

#### Manual Install Instructions

1. Close notepad++
2. Download the plugin from http://chiselapp.com/user/vor0nwe/repository/npp_preview/zip/Preview_plugin.zip?uuid=publish (direct link)
3. Extract the zip file
4. Copy the contents of the zip (`PreviewHTML.dll` and `Config`) to `Notepad++\plugins`
5. Restart Notepad++

   [image]
6. Test the plugin

   [image]